# How to attach generated PDF to .NET SMTP?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdfsharp, system.net.mail

I am using PDFsharp to generate a job report. I need that report automatically attached to an outgoing e-mail. Right now when the user is viewing the job information in a angular modal, they click Email and the report is generated and a new modal appears with the e-mail input fields. How do I setup the Email Controller to find the correct PDF in the JobSetupPdfs folder?

PdfController

```
public string Get(int id = 1)
    {

        JobDataAdapter adapter = new JobDataAdapter();
        Job job = new Job();
        job = adapter.GetJob(id);
        if (job == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        try
        {
        // Create a new PDF document
            PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
            document.Info.Title = "Created with PDFsharp";

         gfx.DrawString("Texas Exterior Systems", HeadingFont, XBrushes.Black,
              new XRect(0, 50, page.Width, page.Height),
              XStringFormats.TopCenter);

            gfx.DrawString("Job Setup Sheet", BodyFont, XBrushes.Black,
              new XRect(0, 80, page.Width, page.Height),
              XStringFormats.TopCenter);

       var filename = string.Format(@"C:\Users\texas_000\Desktop\TexasExterior\TexasExterior\JobSetupPdfs\{0}.pdf", job.JobName);
            document.Save(filename);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Print(ex.ToString());
        }
        return string.Empty;


    }
```

Mail Controller

```
[Authorize]
    public ActionResult EmailPdf( string To, string Cc, string comments, string Bcc, HttpPostedFileBase fileUploader)
    {

        try
        {
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mail.texasicecarving.com", 8889);
            //client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Timeout = 100000;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("postmaster@texasicecarving.com", "******");
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            if (fileUploader != null)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileUploader.FileName);
                msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(fileUploader.InputStream, fileName));
            }
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress( "texas697@gmail.com"));
            msg.From = new MailAddress("postmaster@texasicecarving.com");
           // msg.Subject = name + " " + subject;
            msg.Body = comments;

            //MailAddress Ccopy = new MailAddress(user.Email);
            //msg.CC.Add(Ccopy);

            //MailAddress Bcopy = new MailAddress(Bcc);
            //msg.Bcc.Add(Bcopy);

            client.Send(msg);
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully Sent Message.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Angular Controller

```
 $scope.EmailPdf = function () {
    $http.get('/api/Pdf/{id}').success(function () {
        $scope.PrintPreviewModal();
    });
}
```

Update
OK, so I have it setup with the correct path. Now how do I have it attach the PDF that was just generated? Would I need to add a time stamp to the PDF and have msg.Attachments attach the newest PDF in that folder?

```
 msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(@"C:\Users\texas_000\Desktop\TexasExterior\TexasExterior\JobSetupPdfs\Restoration.pdf"));
```

Comment: You can add the contents of a stream as an attachment. PDFsharp can save the PDF file to a stream.

Comment: @user3919120 See above, use a file stream as the attachment. For debugging purposes, it might be easier to save the file while developing and attach that way. However the real production way is to use the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the attachments collection on the mail message object.

msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(PathToAttachment));

Check out this MSDN article for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.attachments.aspx